# If your atlas is out of alignment, will the rest of your spine be out as well?

Tags: human-biology

I just found out about this association called Nucca. Basically, they are a chiropractic association - their whole idea is that if your atlas is out of alignment, then the rest of your spine is also out of alignment, because your atlas controls it all. Also, the nerves will get pinched and therefore cause pain. 

Is this legit?

Comment: https://www.sciencebasedmedicine.org/the-problem-with-chiropractic-nucca/

Comment: No, it is not. The "theoretic building" of chiropractic is nonsense - see the several [articles](http://edzardernst.com/?s=chiropractic) from Edzard Ernst on it.